# Как правильно называется список при нажатие ПКМ на ярлык в панели задачи?

Tags: java, c#

подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно список при нажатие ПКМ на ярлык в панели задачи? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто мне нужно для приложение сделать подобный список. Может кто подсказать, а то даже не знаю,  как правильно это искать. Прошу помощи.

Comment: [JumpList Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.jumplist?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо. Это и вправду то что мне нужно

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov прошу прощения вы не могли бы подсказать по этому поводу, как это сделать. Я не могу нормально найти информацию по этому?

Comment: Вбиваете в поиск "название языка программирования, название gui-фреймворка, jumplist".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это называется контекстное меню

Comment: Это точно? Просто я не нашел ничего, чтобы можно было сделать именно с контекстным меню.

Comment: Вы спросили что это, я вам ответил

Comment: Хорошо, а вы не работали случайно с ними?

Comment: Нет, не работал, но в java fx есть готовая реализация контекстного меню, правда не знаю, оно вам нужно или нет. В общем почитайте, большинство gui библеотек наверное должны содержать в себе реализации контекстного меню

Comment: Это неверный ответ.